# Are there any authentication plugins that work with DataMapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic, datamapper

I'm in need of an authentication method that works with DataMapper. I can see that the authlogic plugin requires the fields

```
 crypted_password, password_salt, persistence_token
```

in the User model. Is it enough to just add these fields to the User model definition using DataMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[simplest_auth](http://github.com/vigetlabs/simplest_auth)

is compatible with DataMapper

Answer (score 0):

It would need to be significantly more sophisticated than that, since the APIs are quite different between DataMapper and ActiveRecord. However, it appears at least one person is on the same wavelength as you. Check out **[this ticket](http://binarylogic.lighthouseapp.com/projects/18752/tickets/130-datamapper-support)**, which has a link to this **[pastie](http://pastie.org/503478)** that integrates authlogic into a User model using `DataMapper`.